# Require two touches to move map

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have an MKMapView in a UIPageViewController, so I want two touches to be required to drag it so that it does not interfere with paging. I tried this in the MKMapViewDeleate, but it did not work (I could not drag):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    mapView.isScrollEnabled = true
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    mapView.isScrollEnabled = false
}
```

How can I get this to work? Any other suggestions for dealing with a map in an MKMapView are very welcome!

Comment: I would really suggest that you don't do this.  Changing the operation of standard UI elements can confuse users and goes against the iOS Human Interface Design guidelines.  You would also have a discoverability problem; how would people know that they have to use two fingers?  It would be better to have some sort of "handle" that can be dragged to switch pages, leaving the map scrolling as standard.

Comment: @Paulw11 if you were to add that as an answer I think I would accept it